# Is the amount of damage absorbed by diamond skin proportional to weapon damage

Tags: diablo-iii

In diablo 3? Or just level?

Is there a way to improve the damage?

Currently my wizard has 24k energy. An extra 6k diamond skin hold doesn't seem like much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diamond Skin scales with level and damage reduction.

The higher your level, the more damage it absorbs (up to around 10k damage at level 60).
However, it also scales with your defenses, as the damage the shield takes is dealt after armor and resistances.

This means the only way you can improve the absorption on the shield is to either gain levels or gain armor / resistances.

Comment: This is where DS truly shines. If I have 10k HP, and you have 50k HP, but we both have the same effective hp (through armour and resistances), meaning we both die after taking the same amount of damage, my DS is about 5 times more effective than your DS.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge the amount of damage absorbed by Diamond Skin only increases with the Wizard's level. You can check out the values for level 60 in the skill calculator or the [game guide](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/diamond-skin).

Currently the basic Skin absorbs about 10k damage, with the Crystal Shell rune it absorbs 21k.